# Как избежать использования eval set -- при парсинге аргументов?

Tags: bash

При изучении парсинга аргументов скриптами на **bash** с использованием **getopt** почти везде встречаю использование вот такой конструкции: `eval set -- "$SOMETHING_PARSED"`. Например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash?page=1&tab=scoredesc#tab-top) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16483119/an-example-of-how-to-use-getopts-in-bash). Так как планирую в будущем выкладывать свои рабочие скрипты в свободный доступ, то хотелось бы не оставлять такой дыры пользователям. Есть какие-то способы этого избежать?

[Здесь](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/675320/524604) описано, что в зависимости от версии **getopt**, можно обойтись без `eval`. Но, по крайней мере, в моём случае это не так. **getopt** выдаёт вот такую строку, как пример: `' -j --version= '\''1'\'' --number= '\''2'\'' -- '\''2C_IA/GBCs_out/nohope_2C_IA_off.xml'\'''`. И `set` присваивает её полностью к переменной `$1`.

Comment: для себя использую шаблон для **Getting options** из [devhints.io](https://devhints.io/bash#miscellaneous), просто и со вкусом.

Comment: @Zt. Это да, на край возьму в работу. Просто тогда не получится объявлять именованные опции в конце строки после позиционных аргументов.

Comment: `именованные опции в конце строки после позиционных аргументов` - пример можно ?

Comment: Например, порт в `ssh` можно указывать после адреса хоста: `ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=60 -o ServerAliveCountMax=5 user@nodeXX.hpcXX.domain.com -p 10081`.